# Probability of rolling at least one 6 in each roll when rolling multiple dice a number of times

Tags: probability, dice

I roll $n$ fair dice $m$ times in a row. The probability to roll at least one 6 in each roll is $(1 - (5/6)^n)^m$ I think. Is that correct?

How can I find $n$ so that the probability of rolling at least one 6 in each roll is at least 95%?

Can I just say $(1 - (5/6)^n)^m > 0.95$ and solve for $n$? So that $n > \log(1 -0.95^{(1/m)})/\log(5/6)$ ?

Comment: Although I didn't do it, you likely got downvoted because you haven't shown your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: For a clue to an answer, read about the Birthday Problem (probability).

Comment: I edited the question a bit. I don't understand the relation between this and the Birthday Problem.

Comment: Yes, in that $(5/6)^n$ is the probability of no sixes in a given roll.  Keep going!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.